# How can I graph my Gmail?

Tags: gmail, export, statistics

I have a mailbox in Gmail and I would like to create a graph of messages received per day.

What methods could I use for getting out a count per day, such as this:

```
11/2    40
12/2    27
13/2    15
14/2    65
```

(I can access it by IMAP/POP3 and use a local solution, but nothing immediately comes to mind other than writing a script on a .mbox file!)

Answer (score 6):

http://www.graphyourinbox.com/

> Graph Your Inbox is a Google Chrome extension that allows you to graph Gmail activity over time.

hope this helps.

Comment: Came here to recommend the same thing. Guy who did graphyourinbox was an awesome guy. He'll be missed.

Comment: Unfortunately the iGoogle gmail widget that GYI uses to work has changed and the extension no longer works.